# Kinematics Physics Toy

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, projectile

A toy was rolled off the table at 10 m/s and landed 5 m from the table.  The same car is rolled off the same table at 15 m/s.

1. Would the time the car was in the air increase, decrease or stay the same?  Explain why you picked the answer you did.
2. Would the distance the car landed from the table increase, decrease or stay the same?  Explain why you picked the answer you did.

Comment: Hello! Welcome to Physics.SE. When asking about homework problems, please show your attempts and ask about specific concepts that you are stuck on. Simply stating a homework problem will not be well-received. [Here are some tips for asking about homework problems.](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) [Here are some tips for asking good questions in general.](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Remember that we can split the motion of the car into horizontal and vertical components.

If the table is horizontal then the vertical velocity of the car as it leaves the table is zero in both cases. What do you think this means when you compare the time of flight in both cases ?

However, the horizontal velocity of the car is greater the second time round. What do you think this means for the distance that the car travels horizontally before it hits the ground ?